# Webpack only generates JS, no CSS file from SCSS

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack, sass-loader

In my project I use Webpack with React and NodeJS. I want to generate a `bundle.js` and `style.css` file. Currently I've got the following code:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',

  output: {
    path: 'public',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: ''
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass') }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('public/style.css')
  ]
}
```

But when I run `webpack` **only the JS** file is created in the `./public` map:

```
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  844 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 222 hidden modules
```

Following examples/tutorials it's only oriented on CSS files, or obvious mistakes where made like not implementing ExtractText.
I've also downloaded the packages `sass-loader node-sass`. In some examples I did found those packages where included, in some they weren't.

**EDIT (require style in index.js):**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import routes from './modules/routes'

require('./public/style.css')

render(
    <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**EDIT (webpack.config.js):**

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test      : /\.scss$/,
        include   : path.join(__dirname, './public/sass'),
        loaders   : ["style", "css", "sass"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
      }
    ]
  },

  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, './public/sass')]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin(path.join(__dirname, './public/style.css'))
  ]
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
webpack.config.js
index.js

/public
    index.html
    bundle.js (generated)

    /sass
        style.scss
        basics.scss (imported in style.scss)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you require your style file.
e.g.

```
require('../sass/app.scss');
```

and I think you need style loader as well
e.g.

```
{
        test      : /\.scss$/,
        include   : path.join(__dirname, 'sass'),
        loaders   : ["style", "css", "sass"]
}
```

These three loaders perform following operations

1. Turn your `scss` files into plain `CSS` with the **sass loader**
2. Resolve all the `imports` and `url(...)s` in the `CSS` with the help of **CSS loader**
3. Insert those styles into the page with the **style loader**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did add the loader to my code (above the extract loader) and required the css file in my entry, index.js (see my edited code). I also did add the sassLoader again.. Although it still doesn't work. When I run webpack I get the following error: `Error in index.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./public/style.css`. I don't see what I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: You're requiring the wrong file: require `./public/style.scss` not `./public/style.css`; you're using the sass loader not the css loader.

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of the ExtractTextPlugin and the style loader.

```
module: {
  loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!sass-loader'),
      },
  ],
}

...

plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'style.css')), 
],
```

In my working configs, I also have a possibly extraneous entry in resolve:

```
resolve: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader'),
    },
  ],
},
```

The other error might be how you're including it in `index.js`. You're using  `require('./public/style.css')` rather than `require('./public/style.scss')`.